# Sikuli while loop syntax in java

Tags: sikuli

Here is a example of Sikuli script

```
while (exists("OK.png"),10):
    click("OK.png")
```

How can I do the same in Java?

Here is what I tried:

```
Screen screen = new Screen();
Pattern image = new Pattern("OK.png");

while (screen.exists(image))
{
    screen.click(image);
}
```

But it is failing to compile with this exception:

```
java: SikuliTest.java:29: incompatible types
found   : org.sikuli.script.Match
required: boolean
```

Can anyone provide the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html#Region.exists), `exists()` returns a `Match` object if the image was matched, or `null` otherwise.  Try this:

```
while (screen.exists(image) != null)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
Screen screen = new Screen();

try{
    while(screen.exists("OK.png") != null){
    screen.click("OK.png");
    }
}
    catch(FindFailed e){
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
```